# How to debug sql error 3616 "An error was raised during trigger execution"

Tags: sql-server, debugging, triggers, sql-server-2012

I got the error `"An error was raised during trigger execution"` in a production environment.

The error occurs irregulary (once per day or so) and I have not been able to reproduce it in test.

There are a few triggers involved (not my code) and some of them do scary (for me) things you shouldn't do in a trigger. I have access to the source but so far I have not found anything which could cause the error.

The sql error does not give any information on what the problem is so now I need hints on how to debug it. Since it is a production environment I can't touch the triggers but am allowed to use sql trace.

First question is what kind of errors can cause the above message. Is it any error including deadlock, timeouts etc or is it just data related errors (illegal cast, multiple result from sub-query etc)?

Are there any logs/statistics I can look at to exclude some type of errors?

How should I set up an sql-trace to catch the error?

Comment: Profiler  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error 3616 may occur during trigger execution. In this case, the batch will be aborted and the user transaction, if any, will be rolled back. To resolve this problem, you need to rewrite the triggers code.

Comment: "You need to rewrite the triggers code"—can you give more specific guidance on what needs to change in this code?